# Top 10 list of products with child products

Tags: mysql

This is going to be dead easy for any SQL head, but for some reason is alluding me.

```
Table product: product_id, parent_id, etc
Table carts_ordered: product_id, quantity, etc
```

Product children have `parent_id` set to their parent's `product_id`.

This is roughly what I'm doing now:

```
SELECT c.product_id, p.parent_id, SUM(c.quantity) AS su 
FROM carts_ordered c 
LEFT JOIN product p ON (c.product_id=p.product_id) 
WHERE p.product_id IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY c.product_id
ORDER BY su DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

But of course I'm often getting a bunch of child products in the top ten, e.g.:

[image]

I would like to merge the sums for all product children to get a top ten list of parent products (with no child products in the top ten list).

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sine you use `WHERE p.parent_id IS NOT NULL`, `left join` can be replaced by `inner join` instead.

From the description of problem, it is better to sum the `quantity` of parent with all their children's, not just the sum of children'.

```
SELECT 
    p.parent_id + IF(p.parent_id = 0, p.product_id, 0) as ParentID,
    SUM(c.quantity) AS su 
FROM carts_ordered c 
INNER JOIN product p ON (c.product_id=p.product_id) 
GROUP BY ParentID
ORDER BY su DESC LIMIT 0,10;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, clever use of `IF()` — that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you group by parent_id ?

```
SELECT c.product_id, p.parent_id, SUM(c.quantity) AS su 
FROM carts_ordered c 
    LEFT JOIN product p ON (c.product_id=p.product_id) 
WHERE p.parent_id IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY p.parent_id
ORDER BY su DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

does it work ? i dont have mysql installed and can't test.

Comment: This is in the right direction, but falls apart with products that have no children—it's aggregating all the products that have no child (parent_id=0) as a single sum.